# .Net - Dynamically adding ASP button at runtime to table in ASPX

Tags: asp.net, html-table

I need to add button at run time in my table in aspx

```
table.Append("<table border='1' class='table table-striped' width='450px'>");
table.Append("<tr><th>Facilities</th><th>Size</th><th>InterestRate</th><th>View in Doc</th>");
table.Append("</tr>");

if (dr.HasRows)
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        table.Append("<tr >");
        table.Append("<td>" + dr[0] + "</td>");
        table.Append("<td>" + dr[1] + "</td>");
        table.Append("<td>" + dr[2] + "</td>");
        table.Append("<td>" + <asp:Button ID = 'btnOpenDoc' runat = 'server' CssClass = 'button rounded' Width = '200px' Text = 'Open Document' OnClick = 'RunPowerShellScript_OnClick()'/> + "</td>");
        table.Append("</tr>");
    }

}
```

I'm having issue with this line:

```
table.Append("<td>" + <asp:Button ID = 'btnOpenDoc' runat = 'server' CssClass = 'button rounded' Width = '200px' Text = 'Open Document' OnClick = 'RunPowerShellScript_OnClick()'/> + "</td>");
```

Comment: What is the type of your `table` variable? Note also you are creating duplicate IDs as well which is a **VeryBadThing**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't add server controls by concatenating strings.

try this,

PSEUDO CODE

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Table ID="table" runat="server">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>

            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>    
</div>
</form>
```

Codebehind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Button btn = new Button()
        {
            ID = "btnOpenDoc",
            CssClass = "button rounded",
            Width = 200,
            Text = "Open Document"
        };
        table.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Click += RunPowerShellScript_OnClick;
}

protected void RunPowerShellScript_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```